# FOR statement note working

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

Baffled by why this doesn't work. It has worked in the past, I don't know what I changed. I'm not getting any errors, the for loop just isn't running. Stuff before and after the loop is running.

```
for(int i=2; i==length; i++){
    note = note.concat(args[i]);
    sender.sendMessage("Args[i]: " + args[i]);
    sender.sendMessage("Note: " + note);
}
```

Length is an integer holding the length of an 1d array. This error occurs when length is 3 and greater (don't worry about when length < 3 its not meant to do anything).

Comment: Why do you think we should know what's `length`? We don't read minds, yet. Furthermore, since `i!=length`, it won't loop, you want `<` instead.

Comment: If the for loop is not running, that means that length is not equals to 2 before starting the first iteration. Did you meant `for(int i=2; i<length; i++)` ?

Comment: If the loop doesn't run then the loop condition is not fulfilled. Furthermore using `for` makes no sense here with `==` in the condition, as the loop will run exactly once and thus the code is effectively the same as `if (length == 2) { ... }`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The loop is running while `i == length`. That would mean that for the loop to iterate more than once, the variable `length` has to be changed for every iteration, otherwise `i != length`. This does not seem like a legit solution, you probably meant to type `i < length` (equality is rarely used as the termination statement in a for loop).

```
for(int i=2; i==length; i++){
    // This will iterate if length keeps changing to be equal to i.
    // Since you are not changing the value of length in the loop, you are 
    // expecting it to be changed asynchronously somewhere else in the code.
}
```

Comment: Not the DV, but the value doesn't change. He's comparing, not assigning.

Comment: You're asking questions instead of answering them - that's what comments are for. Furthermore, obviously it's correct that the loop is running as long as `i==length`, that's basic programming knowledge...

Comment: @l4mpi of course it is basic programming knowledge, but I don't see why it is wrong to mention it since the question itself is pretty basic knowledge?

Comment: Of course you can mention it, but in your first revision, which I commented on, that was expressed as a question ("is this correct?") which was pretty nonsensical. But anyways, your answer is still bad as 1.) `i <= length` is probably more correct than `<`, 2.) the "lenght has to be changed outside of the loop" part makes no sense at all (from where? a different thread? magic?) 3.) you miss the point that this _can_ still run (for exactly one iteration) if `lenght==2` 4.) using a while loop seems like a bad suggestion (but a for-each loop could be an alternative)

Comment: 1.) args starts its index at 0, which means that i <= length would give him a nullpointer on the last iteration, 2.) I only state that for the loop to keep iterating, length HAS to be changed somehow, and he is not doing it in the loop, 3.) sure it can be run for one iteration, although I highly doubt that was his intention, 4.) OK I agree with you on that one.